# Hacker Rank SQL Problem: 15 Days of SQL, how to select query work with AND

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider the following:

```
create table submissions (
  submission_date date,
  submission_id int,
  hacker_id int,
  score int
  
);

create table hackers (
  hacker_id int,
  name varchar(20)
);

insert into submissions values
("2016-03-01", 8494, 20703, 0),("2016-03-01", 22403, 53473,15),
("2016-03-01",23965,79722,60),("2016-03-01",30173,36396,70),
("2016-03-02",34928,20703,0),("2016-03-02",38740,15758,60),
("2016-03-02",42769,79722,25),("2016-03-02",44364,79722,60),
("2016-03-03",45440,20703,0),("2016-03-03",49050,36396,70),
("2016-03-03",50273,79722,5),("2016-03-04",50344,20703,0),
("2016-03-04",51360,44065,90),("2016-03-04",54404,53473,65),
("2016-03-04",61533,79722,45),("2016-03-05",72852,20703,0),
("2016-03-05",74546,38289,0),("2016-03-05",76487,62529,0),
("2016-03-05",82439,36396,10),("2016-03-05",90006,36396,40),
("2016-03-06",90404,20703,0);

create table colleges (
  college_id int,
  contest_id int
);

insert into hackers values 
(15758, 'Rose'),(20703, 'Angela'),
(36396,'Frank'),(38289, 'Patrick'),
(44065, 'Lisa'),(53473,'Kimberly'),
(62529, 'Bonnie'),(79722, 'Michael');
```

For this HackerRank [quiz](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql/):

> Julia conducted a "15 days of learning SQL" contest. The start date of the contest was March 01, 2016 and the end date was March 15, 2016.

> Write a query to print total number of unique hackers who made at least 1
> submission each day (starting on the first day of the contest), and find the hacker_id and name of the hacker who made maximum number of submissions each day. If more than one such hacker has a maximum number of submissions, print the lowest hacker_id. The query should print this information for each day of the contest, sorted by the date.

Here is solution I am trying to understand:

```
SELECT submission_date, 
        (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT hacker_id)
    FROM Submissions AS SUB2
    WHERE SUB2.submission_date = SUB1.submission_date AND 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT submission_date)
    FROM Submissions AS SUB3
    WHERE (SUB3.hacker_id = SUB2.hacker_id) AND 
    (SUB3.submission_date < SUB1.submission_date)) 
    = DATEDIFF(SUB1.submission_date, '2016-03-01' )
        ),
        
        (SELECT hacker_id FROM Submissions SUB4
        WHERE SUB4.submission_date = SUB1.submission_date
        GROUP BY hacker_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(submission_id) DESC, hacker_id LIMIT 1) AS HID,
        (SELECT name FROM Hackers
        WHERE hacker_id = HID)
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT(submission_date)
FROM Submissions) AS SUB1
```

I am failing to understand 2 parts:

**Part 1**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT hacker_id)
        FROM Submissions AS SUB2
        WHERE SUB2.submission_date = SUB1.submission_date AND 
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT submission_date)
        FROM Submissions AS SUB3
        WHERE (SUB3.hacker_id = SUB2.hacker_id) AND 
        (SUB3.submission_date < SUB1.submission_date)) 
        = DATEDIFF(SUB1.submission_date, '2016-03-01' )
            )
```

**Question for the above code:**
How does this part work:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT hacker_id FROM Submissions AS SUB2 WHERE
SUB2.submission_date = SUB1.submission_date
```

works with

```
(SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT submission_date) FROM Submissions AS SUB3 WHERE 
(SUB3.hacker_id = SUB2.hacker_id) AND  (SUB3.submission_date < 
SUB1.submission_date))  = DATEDIFF(SUB1.submission_date, 
'2016-03-01' ))
```

The first part bring all the unique hacker_id for a given submission date and the second part check if hacker_id made consistent submissions for that date, but how SQL is sure to check only the hacker_id that are present in first part (before AND) in second part (which is after the AND)

Can you please explain with an example how these 2 queries work together?

**Part 2**
For this part

```
 (SELECT hacker_id FROM Submissions SUB4 WHERE
 SUB4.submission_date = SUB1.submission_date GROUP BY hacker_id 
 ORDER BY COUNT(submission_id) DESC, hacker_id LIMIT 1) AS HID
```

How is it checking only those hacker_ids that made consistent submissions on each date uptil the current date for afterwards grouping these hacker_ids submissions and then picking the lowest hacker_id with maximum submission?

[MRE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/844928) for this problem.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, so `SELECT DISTINCT(submission_date)` is a bit silly.

Comment: here we are selecting distinct/unique values from column "submission_date"

Comment: That would be `SELECT DISTINCT submission_date`

Comment: Now I understand this! since it is not a function, column name need not to be within brackets.Thanks @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

It's not what you asked, but these days, we would probably do something like this...

Note that my date range and data set differs slightly from yours...

```
drop table if exists hackers;

create table hackers (
  hacker_id serial primary key,
  name varchar(20)
);

insert into hackers values 
(15758, 'Rose'),
(20703, 'Angela'),
(36396,'Frank'),
(38289, 'Patrick'),
(44065, 'Lisa'),
(53473,'Kimberly'),
(62529, 'Bonnie'),
(79722, 'Michael'),
(10101, 'Geoff');

drop table if exists submissions;

create table submissions (
  submission_date date,
  submission_id serial primary key,
  hacker_id int,
  score int
  
);

insert into submissions values
("2016-03-01", 8494, 20703, 0),
("2016-03-01", 22403, 53473,15),
("2016-03-01",23965,79722,60),
("2016-03-01",30173,36396,70),
("2016-03-02",34928,20703,0),
("2016-03-02",38740,15758,60),
("2016-03-02",42769,79722,25),
("2016-03-02",44364,79722,60),
("2016-03-03",45440,20703,0),
("2016-03-03",49050,36396,70),
("2016-03-03",50273,79722,5),
("2016-03-04",50344,20703,0),
("2016-03-04",51360,44065,90),
("2016-03-04",54404,53473,65),
("2016-03-04",61533,79722,45),
("2016-03-05",72852,20703,0),
("2016-03-05",74546,38289,0),
("2016-03-05",76487,62529,0),
("2016-03-05",82439,36396,10),
("2016-03-05",90006,36396,40),
("2016-03-06",90404,20703,0),
("2016-03-01",90405,10101,12),
("2016-03-02",90406,10101,0),
("2016-03-03",90407,10101,15),
("2016-03-04",90409,10101,60),
("2016-03-05",90410,10101,70),
("2016-03-06",90411,10101,0);


WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT '2016-03-01' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM cte WHERE n < '2016-03-06'
)
SELECT h.*
  FROM cte
  JOIN hackers h
  JOIN submissions s
    ON s.submission_date = n
   AND s.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
 GROUP 
    BY hacker_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.submission_date) = 6
 ORDER
    BY hacker_id
 LIMIT 1
;

+-----------+-------+
| hacker_id | name  |
+-----------+-------+
|     10101 | Geoff |
+-----------+-------+
```